# Android connect to 127.168.1.1, how?

Tags: android, network-programming

I have a server program on my PC which is running and waiting for the Android client.

I set these in my Android code:

```
mHost      = "127.168.1.1"; //or getLocalIpAddress()?
mPort      = 5000;
mSocket    = new Socket(mHost, mPort);
```

And have these permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

When I try to connect to my PC, I get this logcat output:

```
10-08 19:18:40.970: E/ex closeInputOutput(8735): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 19:18:40.970: E/doInBackground Exception(8735):  java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.168.1.1 (port 5000): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I have a router, how can I connect to my PC to 127.168.1.1:5000?

**edit:**

```
public static final String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                String ip4 = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(ip4)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getLocalIpAddress(): " + ip4);
                    return ip4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ServerUtils: getLocalIpAddress(): " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

**this is my new Code, this return 192.168.1.104, wich is not working. with my ipconfig I get 192.168.1.102 (that is the correct.)
So in the last code what is wrong? How can I get the correct local IP?**

Comment: did you forgot to set some permissions in the manifest ?

Comment: Android device is connected to your local network (via wi-fi), not trying to come through the internet on 4g and getting blocked by the router's firewall.  If so, do you have a firewall on the PC (i.e. windows firewall)

Comment: can you post your entire manifest ? be sure that your permissions are at the right hierarchical level.

Comment: sadly the IP is changing, how can I detect the correct Local IP Address in android? It gave me wrong last number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be different in your LAN, but usually the address 192.168.1.1 is the router address (not the host address).

Confirm you host address by running the command:

> ipconfig

at command prompt. The IPv4 address will be the host address and the Gateway address the router address. Be sure to use the correct address on both PC and device.

Note: You need to post the relevant part of your code, both on PC and device, if you want more precise help.

--EDITED--

IP address is like a home address, each device has his own. So when you run ipconfig on the windows machine you get the windows machine ip address. When you call the `getLocalIpAddress()` on device you get the device IP address.

If you want to connect from the device to the PC, you need to:

- Run on the PC a program that listens to the port 5000. If there is no program listening on this port, any attempt to connect to this port will be refused.
- On device you run a program that connects to `192.168.1.102` (pc IP address) at port `5000`

Comment: this is good, but the IP is changing, please see my updated last code

Answer (score 3):

127.168.1.1 is by default in the loopback range, so likely the connection attempt is not leaving your Android device.  try to put your server on a 192.168.x.x ip

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPReservedPrivateandLoopbackAddresses-3.htm

Comment: so how you explain the `java.lang.NullPointerException` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well that is the problem of Firewall.... Go to your router's firewall, or System's Firewall... and add 5000 Port into exceptions list... inbound and outbound too.... And 2nd problem seems with your I.P address... 127 is not a Usable Class... It is Loop back testing (127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254 ...) Change your address from 127 to 192.168.0.1 or 1.1 ...